# How can I debug a built-in maven plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, m2e

I'm getting a NullPointerException when running the maven-assembly-plugin. It appears to be caused by a particular section of my assembly. How can I do source-level debugging of this plugin so I can narrow down the problem?

I'm using Eclipse and M2E.

Comment: Which version of the maven-assembly-plugin? And how does your assembly look like?

Answer (score 5):

To start with, you could run maven with `-X` option.  This would give a lot of `debug` info. If this is insufficient, you could use `mvnDebug`.  [This page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dealing+with+Eclipse-based+IDE) details how to do this using Eclipse.